# Какую нишу занимает Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Привет всем.
Изучаю этот замечательный язык уже 2 месяца,довольно приятный и практичный.

Правда я не очень понимаю:

1. Какую нишу занимает Ruby?
2. Где он используется помимо Rails и других web-framework-ов?
3. Есть ли у него будущее **без Rails**?
4. Что можно на нём писать?

Судя по [этой статье](http://brixen.io/2012/12/11/a-ruby-design-process),сейчас у Ruby дела идут не очень.

Поведайте мне пожалуйста,что и как.

Comment: на днях прошла конференция RailsClub. http://railsclub.ru/ там должны быть видеоотчёты
кто-то говорит о закате руби, а кто-то на нём даже пишет программы для мобильной тройки

Comment: Закат руби и мобильная разработка,звучит странно.Получается они из последних сил пытаются остаться на плаву.

Comment: Вы считаете, что уместно задавать такие вопросы? Ruby субъективно самый удобный язык для вб разработки. В других областях также может применятся, но не так популярен. И язык, и всё вокруг него активно развивается. Хорошо зная Ruby, можно получать зп выше средней по IT.
В плане самого языка мне больше нравится Lua, но развивается она куда менее активно. Haskell замечательный язык, но с крутым порогом изучения.
Вам чего, денег в первый год? Или выбираете платформу на долгие годы вперёд?

Comment: @LimansK, разработка не мобильных приложений, а для ОПСОСов. По моему это серьёзно.

Comment: @pirj в Вашем комментарии смущают слова "объективно" и "самый". Вычеркните -- и текст станет нормальным. Серебряных пуль пока в лавку не завезли...

Comment: Конечно уместно.Мне не хочется тратить свое драгоценное время на изучение технологии которая в один прекрасный момент перестанет существовать,конечно же все технологии устаревают,но что будет если загнется Ruby в ближайшие года 2-3?

Comment: @LimansK, даже если "технология загнется", все равно, "скилл-то не пропьешь".

Comment: @Nofate, но время потраченное впустую вы не вернете..

Comment: К тому же,я не вижу ни одного активного форума или сообщества,ruby-forum.com не в счет.

Comment: Если вы хотите выучиться один раз и использовать только эти знания всю всю жизнь - надо становиться бухгалтером )

Comment: @Nofate, Вы неправы: современный бухгалтерский учет постоянно меняется, меняется законодательная база, бухгалтерские программы, документация и т.п.  Тут скорее надо порекомендовать стать, например, дворником. Методика работы метлой не изменилась за последние несколько сотен лет.

Comment: Тут на вкус и цвет. Я бы порассказал вам про бухгалтеров, особенно в муниципальных учреждениях, но ветка не про них )

Comment: Ну и программисты бывают разные...

Comment: А какие серьезные проекты используют сейчас Ruby без Rails?

Answer (score 6):

Проглядел статью по ссылке, нигде не увидел "у Ruby дела идут не очень". Там написано что было бы неплохо привести в порядок процедуру проектирования языка, но и только.

Ruby это прежде всего язык на котором написан Rails. Не видел никакой статистики, но похоже что у Rails дела идут хорошо, сам фреймворк бесконечно допиливается до идеала, кол-во гемов стабильно растёт.

Насчёт мобильной разработки -- похоже тут Ruby пока не имеет никаких стабильных позиций, говорить о чём-то пока рано. Движение в эту сторону есть, вспомнить хотя-бы [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/)

> Есть ли у него будущее без Rails?

Думаю нет. Об этом языке никто бы и не услышал, если бы не Rails.

Такие дела.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev ruby начал набирать популярность ещё до Rails (ежели склероз мне не изменяет). Но после perl'а я к таким творениям отношусь с изрядной долей здорового скептицизма.

Comment: Да, он имел какое-то небольшое сообщество ещё до Rails, но оно было небольшое, довольно маргинальное. Кроме того, большая часть -- чисто японская.

Comment: Лично я увидел там угрозу,которая способна похоронить Ruby,заодно и Rails.
Matz человек с характером,который принимает решения по поводу дайльнейшего развития языка.Изначально,он был против,чтобы его язык использовался в веб-раработке и всячески мешал этому даже выпусткал патчи с целью сломать рельсы.

На сегодняшный день они хотять привести все в порядок,и создать группу,которая будет принимать решения за Matz-а,и даже ввести права на вето.
А теперь представьте ситуацию,Matz захотел внести какое-то изменение в свой язык,но группа наложила вето.Какова будет его реакция?

Comment: > Matz человек с характером,который принимает решения по поводу дайльнейшего развития языка.

Это опенсорц. Матц принимает решения, пока не самодурит. Начнёт чудить -- форк неменуем, и адекватная часть сообщества последует за форком. Не вижу тут никакой проблемы.

Просто народ пока не сильно хочет сорриться, стоящего повода ещё не было.

Comment: А не слишком много недовольных? JRuby,MRuby,Rubinius?Что значит "пока не сильно хочет"?

Comment: MRuby сам Matz и разрабатывает. А JRuby и Rubinius - адаптации под существующие VM, что вполне хорошо и позитивно. Последние несколько лет вообще повышенный интерес к созданию языков программирования.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev И много случаев таких форков Вы можете назвать? Emacs/XEmacs -- раз, кто больше? Ещё пару-тройку назовите, пожалуйста!

Comment: @alexlz, Вам успешных форков или как всегда?

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, не вижу ничего позитивного в этом.Форки обычныо останавливаются в своем развитии,т.к не имееют должной поддержки.

Comment: @LimansK Вы меня заинтриговали. Просто, по утверждениям Эрика Реймонда, отношение сообщества к мэйнтейнерам традиционно аккуратное, и без согласия последних форки стремятся не делать. Правда эта статья вроде относится к прошлому веку. Давайте "как всегда"

Или "как всегда" -- это оно и есть? Т.е. чудак на букву "М" объявляет, что текущий мэйнтейнер может идти лесом, а он "пойдёт своим путём". И дальше этого заявления дело не движется. Вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: > Форки обычныо останавливаются в своем развитии,т.к не имееют должной поддержки.

Будут они иметь должную поддержку или нет, вопрос исключительно политический. Например LibreOffice -- форк OpenOffice, имеет должную поддержку. Политика.

> по утверждениям Эрика Реймонда, отношение сообщества к мэйнтейнерам традиционно аккуратное, и без согласия последних форки стремятся не делать

Политика же, никто не хочет ссориться. Кроме того, если ключевые разрабы пошлют Матца сейчас, то это может быть некрасиво, сообщество не поймёт. Нужен повод. Политика.

Comment: @alexlz, во всяком случае был когда-то, иначе было бы неясно от чего же форкнулся LibreOffice.

> OpenOffice.org is the open source project through which Sun Microsystems has released the technology for the popular StarOffice[tm] Productivity Suite. All of the source code is available under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL). Sun is participating as a member of the OpenOffice.org community

http://www.openoffice.org/FAQs/faq-overview.html#1

Answer (score 3):

> но время потраченное впустую вы не вернете..

Я как раз о том и толкую, что изучение любого ЯП, принесет вам пользу. Уже при работе с другими ЯП.

> я не вижу ни одного активного форума или сообщества

Западные программисты и opensource-сообщество в частности вообще предпочитают mail-листы. [У ruby их есть](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/rubyonrails-talk). Кроме того есть StackOverflow.

Я вот в свою очередь не вижу ни одного Java-сообщества в России (java-talks не в счет), это ведь не значит что java в России умирает, верно? ;)

А про популярность:

- [Статистика SO vs GitHub](http://sogrady-media.redmonk.com/sogrady/files/2012/09/language-ranking-0912.png) за сентябрь
- Свежий [TIOBE](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html)
- [На информационнах ресурсах](http://langpop.com/)
- Статистика по опенсорц-проектам от [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/p/ruby)
- и немного [инфографики](http://www.impactlab.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/rails_infographic-232342.jpg).

Comment: @Nofate,насчет пользы согласен,всегда полезно знать другие подходы к разработке.По крайней мере Java довольно зрелый яп,и у него много полезной документации,статей и т.д.У Ruby ужасная документация,вызывает чувство отвращения.До сих пор не ясно,что будет с ним в будущем,и для чего он предназначен. Ruby != Rails

Comment: > Ruby ужасная документация

???

я этим пользуюсь: rubydoc.info

Comment: Да да ужасная,а за ссылку спасибо.

Comment: > Ruby ужасная документация

В сравнении с чем?

Comment: По сравнению с тем же Python.Даже у PHP она лучше.В моем понимании документация - это централизованная система,которая находиться не где-то на просторах гугла,а на одном сайте,с нормальным поиском,объяснением и примерами кода.

Comment: На http://ruby-doc.org вроде как все на одном сайте.

Comment: @alexlz,раз мы уже плавно перешли к форкам,приведу несколько примеров, Gnome2/Mate, Mandriva/Mageia,  OpenOffice/LibreOffice, Joomla/Joostina и др.В открытом сообществе это довольно частое явление.Я условно делю форки на 2 типа:
1. Форки,которые создают бывшие разработчики этого продукта,за ними как правило,идет основное сообщество,и
2. Форки,которые,как вы сказали, - "пойдем своим лесом",часто тупиковые."Как всегда" - 2й вариант.

Comment: У руби отличная документация, у Rails еще лучше и удобней - http://api.rubyonrails.org/.

У меня вопрос к автору вопроса: зачем вы задали этот вопрос? если вам не нравится язык, экосистема или ещё что-то, то на выбор есть огромное кол-во других языков.

У руби есть проблемы, довольно много, но все мы, рубисты, любим его за красоту и повышение производительности (труда), который он даёт.

Comment: Nofate, для вас лично:
Если вы хотите выучиться один раз и использовать только эти знания всю всю жизнь, программируйте на ассемблере! 

Comment: @Vlad Liosovsky, 

    и повышение производительности (труда), который он даёт.

Вот это уже интересней. Можно ли пополробнее. Желательно с цифрами и конкретными сравнениями с другими языками для аналогичных задач.

Иначе, абсолютно голословное утверждение.

Comment: Я тут новичок, но насколько я понял, именно @Nofate написал про бухгалтера.
1. Бухгалтеру в странах СНГ приходится пост. переуч. ввиду плодовитости и безответственности депутатов.
2. Я имел ввиду, что система команд не меняется так радикально, как языки программирования. Например, система команд х86 живёт достаточно долго. Процессоры АРМ, думаю то же. Да, там появляются новые команды и даже проприетарные, которые не публикуются.Но в целом, там ситуация гораздо стабильнее, чем в языках очень высокого уровня. 
Хотя в последнее время появились многопроцесс. платформы, типа CUDA, Tegra и т.д.

Comment: @avp, а какого рода цифры вы ожидаете увидеть? Как это проверить? Написание приложения на скорость?

У кода на ruby есть следующее преимущество:

Из-за своего динамизма библиотеки могут себе позволить подгонять друг под друга. Из-за этого гемы очень легко и удобно интегрируются, я такого не видел нигде на других языках/платформах.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, я ожидал подобного ответа (что цифр нет, сравнения на уровне ощущений).

Откровенно скажу, Ruby я не знаю. Поэтому просто интересно. 

Но, мне кажется, что если языку уже больше 10 лет, а он не стал **всеобщим "любимцем"**, то либо это не универсальный язык программирования, либо в нем есть "подводные камни" (м.б. в сопровождении программ), либо он ничем (в плане именно скорости решения (написания кода) задач) существенно не отличается от других.

По сути дела, ведь за 50 лет ничего **действительно** хорошего не сделано. Возможно эта задача принципиально (пока) нерешаемая.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev

     Из-за своего динамизма библиотеки могут себе позволить подгонять друг под друга.

А не могли бы Вы эту фразу расшифровать для человека, ruby абсолютно не знающего? А то меня эта фраза и восхищает и пугает одновременно.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, пока не понятно. Предстоит битва "x86 vs ARM и другие". 
Думаю, что и там, и там есть масса недостатков, которые не позволяют увеличить производительность многопроцессорности из-за совместимости со старьём. И дело не только в процессорах. Нынешняя организация памяти, прерываний, не подходит для многопроцессорных систем. 
Многие упустили время. Вот например, ещё в 2008 написано:
http://habrahabr.ru/post/43905/
Переход от гонки частот к гонке голов поменяет ландшафт и тренды.
Моё мнение - победит автономность. Облака - это нужно, но для работы больше нужна локальность.

Comment: @alexlz, Вы серьезно?

Думал, будет интуитивно понятно, а к серьезному обсуждению сейчас не готов.

Comment: @avp увы, серьёзно. И интуитивно не понятно (сейчас многие вещи должны поменяться. И по чисто научно-техническим, и по социально-экономическим причинам). А серебряных пуль в лавку опять не завезли, хотя в заказе (точно помню) они были.

Comment: > А не могли бы Вы эту фразу расшифровать для человека, ruby абсолютно не знающего? А то меня эта фраза и восхищает и пугает одновременно.

В руби можно доопределать методы для объектов и классов, генерировать методы во время выполнения, есть рефлексия.

Поэтому код из подключаемой библиотеки сам может выяснить, в какой среде он используется, и добавить к нужным классам только необходимые методы (например в зависимости от ORM). Притом в итоге получается так, что порой не заметишь где стандартные методы, а где подключенные сторонним гемом, настолько они консистентно выглядят и используются.

Comment: Как сказал кто-то: "Ruby это Lisp с человеческим синтаксисом"

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev

    Притом в итоге получается так, что порой не заметишь где стандартные методы, а где подключенные сторонним гемом

В дальний лес такие инструменты. По читаемости собирается соперничать с perl'ом -- в лес. Мало ООПеров, у которых в программе всё скрыто в классах, и не поймёшь, какого лешего программа себя так ведёт, пока не просмотришь частокол классов, так ещё и эти. Предсказуемость поведения в глубоком ауте, и без крутого рубинового программера ничего работать не будет. Рецепт -- в морг.

И покажите мне хоть хоть одного человека с рубиновым синтаксисом

Comment: > @Nofate, для вас лично ....

@user005, внезапно. Ассемблером я развлекался еще на втором курсе о0 Да и у меня как раз с "потискать новый язык" just for fun проблем не возникает. Но вообще сам совет про ассемблер весьма хорош. Рынок труда, правда, у эмбедщиков поуже. 

> Вот это уже интересней. Можно ли пополробнее

@avp, вот в данный момент у себя на работе наблюдаю, как человек с нулевым опытом в ruby ваяет учетную систему. Скорость вхождения в тему и получения конкретных результатов очень радует.

Comment: @Nofate, могу только пожелать, чтобы Вам лично не пришлось сопровождать эту учётную систему. Разумеется, если этот человек -- грамотный программист с нулевым опытом в ruby, ситуация может быть нормальной, а если нет -- вас ждёт немало приятных минут и часов в будущем.

Comment: @alexlz, за меня не волнуйтесь, человек грамотный, а решение писать на ruby было тщательно обдумано перед принятием.

Answer (score 0):

[@Vlad Lisovsky](/users/1350/vlad-lisovsky), я не говорю,что он мне не нравится,скорее наоборот.

А задавал вопрос для того,что хочу понять,где и как можно использовать Ruby помимо разработки сайтов.

[@avp](/users/232/avp),

```
то либо это не универсальный язык программирования, либо в нем есть "подводные камни"
```

Вот это я и пытаюсь выяснить,насколько он универсален?

> Из-за своего динамизма библиотеки могут себе позволить подгонять друг под друга.

Наверно имелось ввиду добавление своего функционала в стандартные библиотеки,а так же gems.

---

---

**P.S** Почему я больше не могу добавить комментарий?Или стоит ограничение?

Comment: Вы слышали про системы управления конфигурациями?? На руби есть как минимум 2: chef и puppet. Эти решения набирают популярность, как и понятие DevOps в принципе.

Comment: Нет,не слышал.Просмотрел информацию,насколько я понял это одно из направлений системного администрирования.А как обстоят дела в рунете?

Comment: Есть уже компании, внедряющие такие решение. express42 например.

Answer (score -1):

Лично моё мнение. Нет никакого смысла в высокоуровневом языке, если у него синтаксис, как у ассемблера. в этом плане Руби даст фору всем другим. а взять тот же js(написаный на коленке) , что там ноаого: интерполяция строк, блоки-лямбды, yield, сто лет эти вещи есть в Руби. На чистом Руби пишеться много вещей, мне трудно его заменить при работе с моделями, рельса прекрасно прикручивается с ангуляром-реактом-ноде и пр. и главное Руби популярен у богатеньких американских заказчиков. а будущее, рано или поздно все разрабы перейдут на псевдоязыки, к которым руби ближе всех